# C - Makefile with 2 .c files and 1 .h file, using gnu

Tags: c, makefile, gnu

I have two .c files - sort.c and fileio.c - and the main function is in sort.c. Then I have a .h file - fileio.h. When I manually compile all these files, everything works properly. But I'm having issues with the Makefile.

I have the tabs set up properly for the Makefile instruction lines - not sure if you'd be able to tell by looking at it here. This is what I have so far:

```
CC = gcc
sort : sort.o fileio.o
        gcc sort.o fileio.o -o sort
sort.o : sort.c fileio.c
        gcc -g sort.c fileio.c -o sort.o
fileio.o : fileio.c fileio.h
        gcc -g fileio.c -o fileio.o
```

But when I run this, I get and Undefined Reference to 'main' error...Which I'm super confused about, because there is, in fact, a main() function in sort.c.

Can anyone give me a hint as to where I'm going wrong? I've spent ages going through tutorials and they all get more complicated than I need, and don't address this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build the `.o` objects with the `-c` flag. Otherwise they will be compiled as an executable, which needs the entry point `main()` function. You should also remove `fileio.c` from the compilation rule of the `sort.o` target. And the dependency is likely to be `sort.h` and/or `fileio.h`, but not `fileio.c`. You can also use `$@`, which is the target name, instead of typing it into the rule explicitly.

```
CC = gcc

sort : sort.o fileio.o
        $(CC) sort.o fileio.o -o $@
sort.o : sort.c fileio.h
        $(CC) -g  sort.c -c -o $@
fileio.o : fileio.c fileio.h
        $(CC) -g fileio.c -c -o $@
```

Note that in general it makes sense to use rules that leverage standard variables, for instance

```
$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@
```

and use `CPPFLAGS` and `CFLAGS` for pre-processor and compiler flags respectively.

Comment: Hmmm...okay, that got me close, I think. But the second rule is actually: sort.o : sort.c fileio.c, and I can't have both -c -o if there are multiple .c files, right? When I try, it says "cannot specify -o with -c, -S, or -E with multiple files compilation terminated."

Comment: @user2309856 The point is that `sort.o` should not depend on `fileio.c`. `sort.o` should be the output of compiling `sort.c` only.

Comment: Ooooh, that makes total sense and it's working now! Thank you!